# Insert the code what Jquery load

Tags: jquery, html

I use this code, to load a part of my html into an other. Its works well, but i need to modify this code, to replace the loaded source in the "host html file", because if i see my source code after .load() than i did not see the inserted code in.

Thank you.

```
var AjaxContent = function(){
  var container_div = ''; 
  var content_div = ''; 
  return {
    getContent : function(url){
      $(container_div).animate({opacity:0}, //Turn the opacity to 0
        function(){ // the callback, loads the content with ajax
          $(container_div).load(url+" "+content_div, //only loads the selected portion
            function(){                        
              $(container_div).animate({opacity:1}); //and finally bring back the opacity back to 1
            }
          );        
        });
    },
    ajaxify_links: function(elements){
      $(elements).click(function(){
        AjaxContent.getContent(this.href);
        return false; //prevents the link from beign followed
      });
    },
    init: function(params){ //sets the initial parameters
      container_div = params.containerDiv; 
      content_div = params.contentDiv;

      return this; //returns the object in order to make it chainable
    }
  }
}();
```

EDIT:

Sorry. So, i dont want to modify the file, but i use Yoxview which is need some class, div, etc..to run. I use host.php which will hold the html snipetts from the submenus. If i directly open my submenu.php than everything works well, but if i use host.php and load the snipett from the submenu.php than it seems to everything is ok, the text and images shown, but my script does not run. If i check the source, than i realized my its not changed the text the divs etc..missing. So i tougth i need to append the code which loaded by jquery .load()
Maybee i wrong. Sorry for my poor english.

EDIT 2. 
Maybee this link will help to uderstand my problem:

http://demos.malbecmedia.com/ajax-site-demo/

I use this tutorial. If you see the source after hit the link2 u see the #text div content not change in the source. This is my problem. How to modify the code to change the div content in the source too not just the "frontend".

Comment: You want to use JQuery to change your source file? Not going to happen! (well not directly anyway)

Comment: You cannot write to a file on the server with JQuery. If that is not what you are trying to do then please explain more. If you mean you just cannot see the changes when you right-click and "view source" then I think this is just how it is sometimes. The point is, can you visually see the changes you want? If so, then job done

Comment: I edit my comment..please check it

Comment: Your code is working correctly and the source is updated (even if it doesn't look like it when you view the source). I suspect the problem is with the Yoxview plugin, if your Yoxview scripts are included in the page you're loading through AJAX then these will be stripped out which is probably what's causing your problem.

Comment: DJohnson is correct. Try using firebug (in firefox) to inspect the div, the source is updated, but view source reloads the page, it doesn't show you any dynamic modifications.